# Show that $e^x > 1 + x + x^2/2! + \cdots + x^n/n!$ for $n \geq 0$, $x > 0$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, exponential-function

Show that if $n \geq 0$ and $x>0$, then

$$ e^x > 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Not sure where to get started with this induction proof.

Comment: Yeah, from an exercise set in an induction chapter in a number theory text.

Comment: When $x=1$, $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$, not $e^x>1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$. I think your $>$ should be changed to $=$.

Comment: That would be the case if the $\dots$ were after the $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ term.

Comment: How do you defined $e^x$? Because if you define it in terms of the power series, it is sort of obvious. :)

Comment: Happy with the answer given by Goos below. But feel free to provide  another method of solving it using induction :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Base case:** $e^x > 1$ for $x > 0$.

**Induction:** suppose we are given $k$ such that for all $x > 0$
$$
e^x > 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
Change variables to $t$ and integrate both sides:
$$
\int_0^x e^t \; dt > \int_0^x \left( 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{t^k}{k!} \right) \; dt
$$
$$
e^x - 1 > x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}
$$
$$
e^x > 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}
$$

Note that if $f > g$ on $(a,b)$ and both are integrable, then $\int_a^b f > \int_a^b g$ (not just $\ge$).

Comment: I wish I could favorite answers.

Answer (score 3):

It rather depends on your definition of $e^x$.

Suppose you know $\frac{d}{dx} e^x  = e^x$ and $e^0=1$.

Call $f_n(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!}$.  Then your inductive step could say  $f_{n+1}(0) = 1$ and $\frac{d}{dx} f_{n+1}(x) = f_n(x) \lt e^x$ for $x \gt 0$ so $f_{n+1}(x) \lt e^x$.