# Use mathematical induction to show that eˣ > 1 + ⁿ∑ᵣ xʳ/r!

Tags: inequality, induction, exponential-function, mean-value-theorem

\documentclass{article} \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} \colorlet{LightRubineRed}{RubineRed!70} \colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange} \definecolor{Mycolor2}{HTML}{00F9DE} \begin{document} \pagecolor{black} \color{white}%
Using Mathematical Induction, prove that :
$e^{x}>1+x+{x^2\over 2!}+{x^3\over 3!}+...+{x^n\over n!}$
if $x>0$ and n is any positive integer.

\noindent {\color{LightRubineRed} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm}} \noindent {\color{RubineRed} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}
\begin{itemize} \item \Large \itshape \textcolor{Mycolor1}{My attempt} \item \textcolor{Mycolor2}{Let} $f(x)=e^x-1-x-{x^2\over2!}-{x^3\over 3!}-...-{x^n\over n!}$

\item \textcolor{Mycolor2}{Then need to find} ${d\over dx}f(x)$ \item \textcolor{Mycolor2}{and apply the inequality}$f'(x) > 0$

$f'(x)=e^x-1-x-{x^2\over2!}-{x^3\over 3!}-...-{x^{n-1}\over (n-1)!}$

$f'(x)=f(x)+{x^n\over n!}$\item \textcolor{Mycolor2}{I don't know how to proceed further.Any suggestions, hint would be appreciated.}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

Comment: Which definition of $e$ are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $e^x > 1 + x + x^2/2! + \cdots + x^n/n!$ for $n \geq 0$, $x > 0$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667998/show-that-ex-1-x-x2-2-cdots-xn-n-for-n-geq-0-x-0-by-in)

Comment: We have $e^{n}=1+n+\frac{n^{2}}{2!}+\cdots$ so $e^{n}>1+\sum \frac{n^{j}}{j!}$.

Comment: @angryavian e ≈ 2.7182 which is the limit  x->0 (1 + x²)^(1/x²)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you so much

Comment: You cannot use `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[dvipsnames]` etc. in mathjax.